# Intel Vtune Amplifier 2018 Update 2 Results Database Not Created

Tags: c++, profiler, intel-vtune

I'm trying to profile a piece of *C++* code compiled using *VS2017* more specifically `v141` build tools, its takes about `2.5` min to run in the release configuration.

My problem is no matter what I do when I try to profile it with vtune the results database is not created and I get a database interface error.
I have tried to use debug mode, uninstall and reinstall vtune however nothing, I have also tried running in `admin` mode and nothing, I am using the latest update for windows `10` as my OS.

the specific `error` I get is :

> May 15 2018 14:24:04 Cannot finalize the result. Error 0x4000002a (Database interface error) -- Cannot open result database `projectPath\j\r005hs\sqlite-db'.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Can you please check if there are non-english characters in the projectPath? Can you try to copy 'projectPath\j\r005hs' to any 'simple' writable path and open r005hs in VTune? 
Are you running analysis directly from VS2017 or using VTune standalone GUI (amplxe-gui.exe)? Does it happen for Advanced Hotspots analysis type? Can you please check the directory projectPath\j\r005hs\data.0 has non-empty files?

Comment: Hi! My path did in fact have non-english characters in the project path, after I moved the project to my C drive and ran amplifier the profiller did in fact run fine so its seems to be a problem with amplifier not being able to handle non-english characters. Regarding your other questions I rain both vs2017 and the Amplifier application. It was happening on both basic and advanced Hotspots analysis.the directory you mentioned was also non empty.
Thank you for the help.